# Burninate/selectively re-tag [words]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/words) has roughly 500 questions, predominantly by new users, and seems to be used as either as the poor-man's [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) or to fill a square on a newbie's bingo card when adding tags to his/her first question.

[To formally rationalize this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No, most software contains or deals with words.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

If [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) is *actually* meant by its use, totally.  Otherwise, it is *too vague* to say "no", much like any post could be tagged with [computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computers).

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

I think not and wholesale merging [words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/words) with [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) would pollute the latter.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Yes and no.  It's a way to group distinct elements of speech/writing and also *could* be used to denote a chunk of data for an instruction set, but I don't see it being used that way due to new programmers not being aware of that denotation.  For usages of the latter, a tag that's not as likely to be confused with strings is preferable.

Any last [words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/words)?

Comment: Your last line is more suited as the title here! *Any last [words] before we burninate this tag* :P

Comment: Are you sure you don't also want to take another look at [tag:word]? I think I removed most things which were grossly wrong, but who knows what's left.

Comment: @Deduplicator [tag:word] is a separate matter and I'd prefer to focus on [tag:words] as I haven't really looked at what's going on in the prior tag.

Comment: I'm honestly surprised to see no questions about (Microsoft) Word in a quick glance through the first page of the latter tag.

Comment: @neminem Deduplicator just stated that he removed most things which were grossly wrong in that tag... probably includes such questions.